# How to stop empty input fields from affecting calculations in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form which calculates the sum and average of a set of user entered values. Users can dynamically add input fields so that they may find the sum and average of as many data values as they wish. I am trying to proof it such that if they happen to add a field but leave it blank, that input field will be ignored in the calculations. When left blank at present, the form returns 'NaN,NaN'. I have tried this

```
$(':input[value=""]').attr('name', '');
```

based on a quick search, but it did not have the intended effect (the form still returns 'NaN,NaN'.

The calculations are performed when the user clicks a button using the following jQuery

```
$(".calc").click(function() {
   $("input[type=text]").each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).val());
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());       
  });

  var n = arr.length;
  var AVG = (sum / n);
  alert(sum + "," + AVG);
  arr = [];
  sum = 0;
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use an if statement to check what $(this).val() is. If the field is empty, it should return an empty string which is giving you NaN when you try calling parseInt on it.

Comment: Why not just check each field and, if it's blank, subtract one from the number of total fields to divide by and ignore the value of the field?

Comment: Added a simple || operator. check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this below. I have added trim as well to filter the empty spaces.

```
$(".calc").click(function() {
   $("input[type=text]").each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).val().trim() || 0);
    sum += parseInt($(this).val().trim() || 0);       
  });

  var n = arr.sort().filter(function(i){return i}).length;
  var AVG = (sum / n);
  alert(sum + "," + AVG);
  arr = [];
  sum = 0;
});
```

Comment: So close! It still divides the sum by the total number of visible inputs. If there's 3 and one's empty, for example, the average is calculated using 3 data values. It did solve the 'NaN' problem though, but that's because it simply puts a value of 0 in the blank field.

Comment: aside: `.filter(function(i){return i})` == `.filter(Boolean)` (less typing)

Comment: @dandavis is also valid one !

Comment: Thanks to you both! Works perfect.